# SetValue doesn't update UI but OnPropertyChanged does

Tags: c#, mvvm, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a TwoWay binding that controls the value of a slider:

```
<Slider Orientation="Vertical" Height="200" Value="{Binding Path=MapScale, Mode=TwoWay}" Maximum="{Binding MaxScale}" Minimum="{Binding MinScale}" StepFrequency="0.1" />
```

The binding is in the ViewModel as a DependencyProperty:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MapScaleProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("MapScale", typeof(Double?), typeof(MappingPageViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public Double? MapScale
    {
        get { return GetValue(MapScaleProperty) as Double?; }
        set { SetValue(MapScaleProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("MapScale"); }
    }
```

As the code is now, the slider updates properly when I update MapScale (e.g. `MapScale += .1`). But, if I remove the `OnPropertyChanged` method (which I was under the impression `SetValue` already calls), the slider doesn't update properly.

What have I missed?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a dependency property rather than a regular property? I don't think I've seen examples of using DPs in a viewmodel and when it comes to viewmodels, I've always used plain old properties myself.

Comment: DPs seemed to be the way to go for Metro apps. With plain old properties, did you use OnPropertyChanged or something else?

Comment: Yup, `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slider.Value is of type `double`, not `Nullable<double>`. I've noticed that WinRT is very picky about matching binding types. It doesn't auto-convert most things for you like WPF and Silverlight.

My answer is:

Use `INotifyPropertyChanged` as @Adi already mentioned AND use `double` as the property type.

If you're stuck using `Nullable<double>` in your view-model, then create an `IValueConverter` that converts null to zero.